# Invoking a function expression with hanging Parens Vs Function.prototype.call

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between using the standard hanging parens method for invoking the function expression and using `.call` in Javascript?

I sometimes see IIFEs invoked like

```
(function(){
    //your code here
}).call(this);
```

as opposed to the more standard

```
(function(){
    //your code here
})();
```

What is the advantage of using `.call` if any?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It just depends on your scope.

If it is in the global scope, then using `.call(this)` has absolutely 0 effect because `this` was already the `window` object.

If you are in a nested scope somewhere, and want to use the `thisBinding` (`this`) then using `.call(this)` is very important (or storing `this` in a variable such as `self` or `that`). The IIFE is going to be executing at the global scope, so its `this` binding is going to change to the `window`. If an attempt to use `this` is made in that scope, and `this` isn't properly bound, then it will be referencing the wrong object.

Here is an example:

```js
window.x = 5;

(function(){
    console.log(this.x);//5  
})()

var obj = {
    x : 6,
    test : function(){
      (function(){
          console.log(this.x);//5
      })()
    },
    close : function(){
     (function(){
          console.log(this.x);//6
     }).call(this)
    }
};

obj.test();
obj.close();
```

Comment: It's not executed at the global scope, but in the global **context**. Scope applies to ordinary variables, context applies to the special variable `this`.

Comment: @Barmar - Scope is a language agnostic term. The more granular term of **execution context** is not as widely understood so in general I tend to not use that word to avoid confusing others. Feel free to read more about this language agnostic term here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science) or perhaps search on google for its meaning.

Comment: My point is that Javascript has different scoping for `this` than ordinary variables. Ordinary variables use lexical scoping, while `this` is treated specially. And in Javascript, the special way that `this` works is called the function's context.

Comment: It actually isn't though. It is called its `thisBinding`. The `ExecutionContext` contains 3 main facets, a `LexicalEnvironment`, a `VariableEnvironment`, and a `thisBinding`.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know that level of detail. The main point I wanted to make is that unqualified "scope" is usually used to mean the lexical environment.